# Smooth scrolling when clicking on anchor link

Tags: quasar-framework, quasar

Is there a component/utility that helps with smooth scrolling when we click on an anchor link (e.g., https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_smooth_scroll.asp#section2 ) in Quasar?

Answer (score 0):

There is one method **scrollIntoView** provide similar type of functionality.

```
<div ref="about">
about
</div>
<div ref="projects">
projects
</div>

<div class="text-color q-mx-md cursor-pointer text-weight-bolder" @click="$root.$emit('goAbout')">01. About</div>
<div class="text-color q-mx-md cursor-pointer text-weight-bolder" @click="$root.$emit('goProjects')">02. Projects</div>
   

methods: {
    go(ref) {
        this.$refs[ref].scrollIntoView({
            behavior: 'smooth',
            block: 'start',
            inline: 'start'
        })
    },
},
mounted() {
    this.$root.$on('goAbout', this.go.bind(this, 'about'));
    this.$root.$on('goProjects', this.go.bind(this, 'projects'));
}
```